# Extract/scrape a javascript window.open from a static html file using php

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom, scrape

I'm trying to scrape a bunch of local html files. Each one has a piece of javascript embeded inside the file, with a different window.open path, like so:

```
<script>

function goTo() {

if (document.getElementById('somedomain').checked) {
window.open("http://www.somedomain.com");
}

if (document.getElementById('visit').checked) {
window.open("http://extract-this-url.com/?somevar=12345&anothervar=59305&etc=etc");
}

}
</script>
```

I'm trying extract that second URL - it'll be a different URL for each file (As will the first 'somedomain' url).

I've been looking at [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) but it doesnt look like it can do javascript thats embedded within a HTML file.

Is there any decent way of doing this?

Comment: HTML parsers parse HTML, not JavaScript ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regexp:

```
preg_match('#visit.*?window\.open\("(.*?)"#is',$text,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Cant seem to get that to work - just getting an empty array. I assume in the example, $text would just be the HTML source fo the file to extract from, correct?

Comment: My mistake, it should be #is no #s . Edited it now =)